# After installing rbenv and changing Ruby version, Rake no longer runs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler, rbenv

After installing Rbenv and Ruby 1.9.2 and 1.8.7, and setting the current project to use 1.9.2 (it previously used 1.8.7), Rake will no longer run.  Running `rake routes` gives the messages:

```
Could not find rake-0.8.7 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

This after runing `bundle install`.

Trying `bundle exec rake routes` (which is the method used prior to installing Rbenv), produces the following errors:

```
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:3.
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jackrg/Documents/Novelty-Stats/vendor/local/ruby/1.8/specifications/jquery-rails-1.0.19.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-26 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/jackrg/Documents/Novelty-Stats/vendor/local/ruby/1.8/specifications/tilt-1.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-25 00:00:00.000000000Z"
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/source.rb:161.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#each is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#each called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.9/lib/bundler/source.rb:161.
Could not find rake-0.8.7 in any of the sources
```

Note that the application itself runs without issue in development (`rails c`, `rails s`, etc.).

Also note that `gem list` lists rake (0.8.7) as a local gem.

If I change the gemfile to request rake version 0.9.2 and then update the bundle (bundle update rake), I get the same errors except that they now refer to version 0.9.2 of rake instead of 0.8.7.

Comment: Have you run `rbenv rehash` after installing the rubies? Also, have you followed instructions on adding the shims directory to your path?

Comment: I did `echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile` followed by `exec $SHELL` as described in steps 3 and 4 of Section 2.1 of Sam Stephenson's doc on installing rbenv, if that's what you mean.  I'm not aware of any other step to enable the shims.  Is there an independent way to test that shims are enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root cause was the gem file, which still referenced `ruby-debug`.  Changed it to `ruby-debug19`, did a `bundle install` and a `bundle update`, and now rake works fine.  Can't explain why application ran okay with the reference to ruby-debug.

Answer (score 5):

After installing the new ruby version, you'll need to run `rbenv rehash`.  Next, run `gem install rake` then run `rbenv rehash` a second time as rake installs binaries.

Comment: Did that.  Now getting `Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources` and `Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.`  Ran `bundle install` and got `Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracker at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it`.  Reporting the error as requested.

Comment: After searching google, tried `bundle update`, which bombed after reporting it was installing linecache (0.46) with the error 'Can't handle 1.9.x yet' from ruby gems/installer.rb (line 552).

Comment: Looking back up at your first error, there are mentions of system ruby (`/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/...`).  I suspect you may have tried to install rake before you did the first rehash, which has confused things.If I were you, I'd delete the `~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2` directory and start again.  Also, did you add `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to `~/.profile` after you installed rbenv and **before** you installed a new version of ruby?

Comment: So if I understand your recommendation correctly, I should delete the ruby 1.9.2 directory from rbenv, re-install ruby 1.9.2, rehash, install rake, then rehash again.  Correct?

I did add the `rbenv init -` command to my bash startup file.  Can't guarantee whether I did it before or after installing new version of ruby.  But I did restart the shell after adding the command (i.e. exec $SHELL).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The cause for my problem was that Rake was also found in `/usr/bin/local/` in addition to being in the shims directory in rbenv. To check if this is the problem first uninstall rake `gem uninstall rake` then run `which rake`. If you get back a path that is different than `/Users/username/.rbenv/shims/rake` then just remove that binary using `sudo rm /path/to/file`.

Note that in my case at least, `which gem` was using a shimed executable that was managed by rbenv, while rake wasn't. So everything worked find until I tried to invoke `rake command` from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#readme) instead of rbenv. Unlike rbenv, chruby does not rely on shims; so no more having to run `rehash` all the time. Instead, chruby only modifies `PATH`, `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH`.