# Could not find rake-10.0.3 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, capistrano

I successfully installed a Rails (3.2.10) app on an Ubuntu 12.04 server on Rackspace following Railscasts 335 deploying to a vps. Nginx, Unicorn, rbenv and Capistrano.

Then, when I try to install a second rails website I get the error "Could not find rake-10.0.3 in any of the sources" during cap:deploy. cap:setup and cap:check were successful. Additionally, there is no current directory under my application folder.

If I cd into the releases directory and run bundle install it is using rake-10.0.3. The only difference between the two apps is that the new app I am trying to install uses the assets pipeline.

Here is my deploy file which is identical for both apps, except for the set :application directive.

```
set :user, 'mark'
set :scm_passphrase, 'xxxx'
set :domain, '99.99.99.99'
set :application, "my_app"

set :repository,  "#{user}@#{domain}:git/#{application}.git"

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}"

role :app, domain
role :web, domain
role :db,  domain, :primary => true

default_run_options[:pty] = true

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

set :scm, 'git'
set :branch, 'master'
set :scm_verbose, true
set :use_sudo, false

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

Comment: I finally fixed this by installing rails and other gem to system from my home directory using sudo. Very strange since the first application did not require this. Running bundle install said all were already being used. Next it failed to start /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp. I tried to start it manually but an error claimed it did not exist

Comment: Firstly, capistrano was unable to complete as it could find no gems. This despite another app running perfectly. So, I installed the gems as system gems. Bundle seems to want to use these instead of installing its own gems. Now the unicorn does not exist after running unicorn_rails -c /var/www/my_app/config/unicorn.rb -D

Comment: `initialize': Address already in use - /tmp/.sock (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

Comment: Both of my app have this line in unicorn.rb: listen "/tmp/.sock", :backlog => 64 This is in addition to the line listen "/tmp/unicorn.my_app.sock" which is different for both apps.

Comment: It seems the names you use for the `socket` file are the same for your applications . You can try to change one of them and restart nginx . The naming of the `socket` file is in the `server` section of your `nginx.conf' file in `config` directory . After update you should redeploy it to allow capistrano re-link the newly formed values.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22234/discussion-between-mango-and-qumara-sixonetour)

Comment: Did my answer solvs your problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Remove all the versions of Rake  ==> `gem uninstall rake`
Remove Gemfile.lock              ==> `rm Gemfile.lock`
Run bundle install               ==> `bundle install`

```
gem install rake --version=10.0.2
```

if you still get the error then put this into your gemfile.

```
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
```

Comment: In case someone comes to this page with the same issue as I had.
If you are deploying a rails app using capistrano 3 you should add `require 'capistrano/rails'` at the top of Capfile.

Comment: I'm deploying a rails app. I added `require 'capistrano/rails'` to the top of the Capfile and tried again. Same error. So I don't know if that is a solution. For some reason it needs rake at the system level and not in the vendor/bin folder.

Answer (score 7):

```
bundle update rake
```

worked for me. I've had similar problem.

Answer (score 5):

If your still looking for a fix... For me it was a matter of using `sudo bundle install` instead of just `bundle install`.

Comment: This worked. Can anyone tell me why that happens? It's like the OS is keeping to gem bundles in parallel..

Answer (score 2):

I had this same cryptic error message .... turns out I had created a 'cloned' release inside the release folder which causes sprockets to want to do things there .... I think cap uses the create date as it traverses the release tree so somehow this messed things up .... be sure there are no additional 'hand made' folders in your /releases/ folder and you should get past this bug

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The cause for my problem was that Rake was also found in `/usr/bin/local/` in addition to being in the shims directory in rbenv. To check if this is the problem first uninstall rake `gem uninstall rake` then run `which rake`. If you get back a path that is different than `/Users/username/.rbenv/shims/rake` then just remove that binary using `sudo rm /path/to/file`.

Note that in my case at least, `which gem` was using a shimed executable that was managed by rbenv, while rake wasn't. So everything worked find until I tried to invoke `rake command` from the terminal.

Also see: [After installing rbenv and changing Ruby version, Rake no longer runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694219/after-installing-rbenv-and-changing-ruby-version-rake-no-longer-runs/21034433#21034433)

Answer (score 0):

For rails version from 4.3, let try with `bundle exec rails app:update`. It worked for me.

Hope it's useful for you.