# Could not find rake-10.0.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, passenger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could not find rake-10.0.3 in any of the sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169828/could-not-find-rake-10-0-3-in-any-of-the-sources)

I have been trying to deploy a rails 3 app onto bluehost using capistrano. And this error pops up
`Could not find rake-10.0.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`

I have `rake 10.0.3` installed. And here's the error log

```
0   /home/myaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb    90  in `materialize'
1   /home/myaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb    83  in `map!'
2   /home/myaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb    83  in `materialize'
3   /home/myaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb  113 in `specs'
4   /home/myaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb  158 in `specs_for'
5   /home/myaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb  147 in `requested_specs'
6   /home/myaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb 23  in `requested_specs'
7   /home/myaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb 11  in `setup'
8   /home/myaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb 116 in `setup'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what command did you run before this poped out?

Comment: actually, it wasn't a command. the error appears on the page

Answer (score 1):

seems like you are not using the correct gem set with rvm. Because of that even though you can see the gem installed, its not picked up by the rvm . Sometime back I wrote this blog post regarding how to [create gem sets with rvm](http://keepthingssimple.tumblr.com/post/11274588229/using-rvm-to-keep-things-simple)

try to create a rvm gem set which has rake 10.0.3, and then try to run bundle install again.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to your Gemfile may solve the problem:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

For some reason I had removed it myself.

Comment: I have that line in my Gemfile. I just gave up on bluehost and moved to a dedicated hosting.

Comment: Yea, it's working out fine now

Comment: Adding source 'https://rubygems.org' worked for me. I had originally had source 'http://rubygems.org' but that wasn't working after I upgraded to ruby 2.0.0 so I removed it. Guess it just needs the 'https'