# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ffi" in jekyll

Tags: rubygems, bundler, ffi

I do these commands for install jekyll :
gem install bundler_bundle install_bundle update

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ffi":
      In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    ffi (= 1.15.0)

  In Gemfile:
    bootstrap (~> 4.4.1) was resolved to 4.4.1, which depends on
      sassc-rails (>= 2.0.0) was resolved to 2.1.2, which depends on
        sassc (>= 2.0) was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
          ffi (~> 1.9) x64-mingw32

    bootstrap (~> 4.4.1) was resolved to 4.4.1, which depends on
      sassc-rails (>= 2.0.0) was resolved to 2.1.2, which depends on
        sassc (>= 2.0) was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
          ffi (~> 1.9)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did these steps and my problem was solved

first i tried  this command

```
bundle add webrick
```

Then I saw into this problem

**Could not find rake-13.0.1 in any of the sources Run `bundle install` to install missing gems**.

Finally, I solved the problem by following the steps below

1. Remove all the versions of Rake ==> gem uninstall rake
2. Remove Gemfile.lock ==> rm Gemfile.lock
3. Run bundle install ==> bundle install

Then

```
gem install rake --version=10.0.2
```

if still you have this problem check this [Other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169828/could-not-find-rake-10-0-3-in-any-of-the-sources)